# ¿Cómo hago para crear un botón de salida con un TextView?¿Es posible o no?¿Cual podría ser una alternativa?

Tags: java, android-studio

estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Android Studio y la verdad soy nueva en esto, estuve realizando una pantalla flotante el cual necesitaba un botón para poder salir o eliminar la pantalla, he realizado múltiples métodos pero no me han funcionado, ya que cuando ingreso a la aplicación solo se carga la primera pantalla que es de login y luego se sale diciendo que la aplicación ha fallado, nose si el código tenga algún error o lo que intento hacer esta mal y no se puede. por favor podrían ayudarme?

Aquí les dejo el código de mi fragmento.xml ya que estoy usando por fragmentos el botón del cual hablo es el  `<TextView android:id="@+id/txtclose2"`que simplemente es un TextView con un aspecto de un boton de X que seria para salir de esa ventana:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".saldoFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="700dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/green_e"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingStart="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtclose2"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:background="@drawable/cerclebackground"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="X"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="CARGAR SALDO"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/saldos_imagen_app" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Saldo actual"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="$ 0,00"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Ingrese dinero desde"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bottom_Saldo1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/green_F"
            android:text="mercado pago"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:cornerRadius="20dp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bottom_Saldo2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/green_F"
            android:text="PU"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:cornerRadius="20dp" />


    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Aquí también dejo el fragmento .java, no se en cual de los dos archivos se encontrara el error, las partes que aparecen comentadas son los métodos que probé para verificar si funcionaba pero cuando ejecutaba no me dejaba ingresar a la app y me decía que estaba fallando:

```
    package com.example.sdems;
    
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
    
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    
        //Dialog myDialog;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

       /* myDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        TextView txtclose2 = view.findViewById(R.id.txtclose2);
        txtclose2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });*/

        /* TextView txtclose2;
        txtclose2 = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtclose2);
        txtclose2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });*/

        Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment1btn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saldoFragment showPopUp = new saldoFragment();
                showPopUp.show(((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager(), "showPopUp");
            }
        });
    }

}
```